# can not forward message in telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, chatbot

[image]

After getting "yes", the chatbot query function will not run and will send the previous message again. Can anyone help?

Comment: you are calling `self.chatbot()`. in your `chatbot(self, bot=None, update=None)` method `bot` will be `None`. Thus you can't do `bot.forward_message(...)`.

Comment: If I do not have a default value when calling a function, the function asks me for a value. How can this problem be solved?